# ffmpeg emscripten hangs inside tcp_open

Tags: http, ffmpeg, webassembly, emscripten

I've build ffmpeg from sources in emscripten. But can't get it to open http file in a web app in emscripten. I'm calling avformat_open_input() with `http://server.com/file.mpg`. Ffmpeg tries to establish a tcp connection to `tcp://server.com:80` and hangs inside `tcp_open()`. I can see the server prints `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200` but the response doesn't seem to reach back to ffmpeg.

I suspect the browser blocks this connection. Is there way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having to use ffmpeg in emscripten. I ended up implementing my own AVIOContext with custom implementations of read and seek functions. Then pass this context to avformat_open_input().